# Http Client Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, request

I'm trying to type the return of my request however I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'. Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'AccountModel[]': length, pop, push,
>   concat, and 25 more

I request is as follows:

```
 getAccounts(): Observable<AccountModel[]>
    {
        return this.http.get(`${this._configShared.getApiUrl()}`, this.httpOptions);
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance...

I did the following and it also did not work:

```
getAccounts(): Observable<AccountModel[]>
    {
        return this.http.get<AccountModel[]>(`${this._configShared.getApiUrl()}`, this.httpOptions);
    }
```

error:

> Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Type 'HttpEvent' is
>   not assignable to type 'AccountModel[]'.
>       Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'AccountModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: Where are you importing `Observable` from?

Comment: please share your import statments and httpOptions

Comment: httpOptions is a object any. The import from Observable is: 'import { Observable } from "rxjs";'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
return this.http.get(`${this._configShared.getApiUrl()}`, this.httpOptions);
```

to

```
return this.http.get<AccountModel[]>(`${this._configShared.getApiUrl()}`, this.httpOptions);
```

Comment: I did so, but it did not work either. I updated my question with the new error